# unpacking of unequal list of lists into a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the below list of lists in the variable `mydata`

```
[
  [["item1"], ["2016","value1"], ["2017","value2"], ["2018","value3"], ["2019","value4"]],
  [["item2"], ["2016","value1"], ["2017","value2"], ["2018","value3"], ["2019","value4"]],
  [["item3"], ["2016","value1"], ["2017","value2"], ["2018","value3"], ["2019","value4"]],
  [["item4"], ["2016","value1"], ["2017","value2"], ["2018","value3"], ["2019","value4"]],
]
```

I have been trying to put it into a dataframe such as below:

```
index     item1  | item2  | item3  | item4
2016      value1 | value1 | value1 | value1
2017      value2 | value2 | value2 | value2
2018      value3 | value3 | value3 | value3
2019      value4 | value4 | value4 | value4
```

However, when I tried `DataFrame(mydata)`, it gives me the below result:

```
index   0                 | 1                 | 2                 | 3  
item1   ["2016","value1"] | ["2017","value2"] | ["2018","value3"] | ["2019","value4"]
item2   ["2016","value1"] | ["2017","value2"] | ["2018","value3"] | ["2019","value4"]
item3   ["2016","value1"] | ["2017","value2"] | ["2018","value3"] | ["2019","value4"]
item4   ["2016","value1"] | ["2017","value2"] | ["2018","value3"] | ["2019","value4"]
```

I think it is because of the nature of `mydata` where the list of lists is unequally distributed. But is it possible to unpack it into the `dataFrame` as i've specified? Or do I have to create a for loop to go through each element and unpack it to the `dataFrame`?

Answer (score 2):

One way by creating `dict` first:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({l[0][0]:dict(l[1:]) for l in mydata})
print(df)
```

Output:

```
       item1   item2   item3   item4
2016  value1  value1  value1  value1
2017  value2  value2  value2  value2
2018  value3  value3  value3  value3
2019  value4  value4  value4  value4
```